# asp.net timeout of page

Tags: asp.net, authentication, timeout

I have a timeout below and wanted to make sure it works properly:

I have the following in my web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="SVideo/Login.aspx" timeout="2" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

For the login page I have the following code (Note that I am using Login control that comes with asp.net:

```
protected void LoginUser_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
   var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(LoginUser.UserName);

   if (roles.Contains("StUser"))
   {
      const string url = "~/SVideo/WatchLive/Watstream.aspx";
      Response.Redirect(url);
   }
   else
   {
      lblMessage.Text = "Wrong UserName/Pwd Combination";
   }
}
```

UPDATE: Note that inside of the SVideo folder I do have the following code:

Inside SVideo I have the following code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
     <system.web>
       <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />            
      </authorization>
     </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Inside SVideo/WatchLive I have the following code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
    <system.web>
    <authorization>           
        <allow roles="StUser" />
        <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
    </system.web>
   </configuration>
```

My question is that when the user goes to Watstream.aspx after they have been validated as being part of StUser role, I was expecting the page to time out after 2 minutes after no activity as this is what I have for the timeout. Instead even after 2 minutes I do not receive the timeout message.

Also note that my goal is actually to have it timeout after 2 days but I was doing this just to make sure for 2 minutes it does what I expected it to do.

Comment: Do you have any `web.cofig` authorization inside SVideo and SVideo/WatchLive folders? Or any authorization at all except main web.config?

Comment: Yes Win is right you may need to ensure you're denying anonymous users...

Comment: @Win - Hi Win,  do  have web.config in the separate folder. I updated what I did above.

Answer (score 0):

For the timeout to trigger, you have to postback to the server.

Try this:

1. Put a button on Watstream.aspx and bind the onclick event to postback to the server
2. Log in on the site
3. Wait 3 minutes on the Watstream.aspx page and then click the button
4. If you did everything correctly, you should be redirected to your login page,

Also, if this doesn't work clear all the cookies from your browser and try again